cfn-lint a string or stream input is required
I updated cfn-lint to version 1.8.2. Now we're getting a lot of errors that I couldn't find solutions for online.
This is the error message:
E1101 Exception 'a string or stream input is required' raised while validating 'cfnLint'
And this is our template
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Document"
    Metadata:
      cfn-lint:
        config:
          ignore_checks:
            - E1029
    Properties:
      DocumentType: Command
      Content: '{
                    "schemaVersion": "2.0",
                    "description": "Backup",
                    "mainSteps": [
                      {
                        "action": "aws:runPowerShellScript",
                        "name": "Backup",
                        "inputs": {
                          "runCommand": [
                          "$s3install = aws cloudformation list-exports --query \"Exports[?Name==''s3InstallFiles''].Value\" --output text",
                          "aws s3 cp s3://[BucketName]/Backup.ps1 c:\\Backup.ps1",
                          "c:\\Backup.ps1",
                          "if ($?) {exit $LASTEXITCODE } else { exit 255 }",
                          "Write-Output \"Fertig. Erfolgreich\""
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }'

